# Django social auth Error

Tags: python, django, django-socialauth, python-social-auth

When i try to login with Google on Django , i get this error:

```
NoReverseMatch at /social/complete/google-oauth2/

Reverse for 'authorize' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{}' not found. 0 pattern(s) tried: []
Request Method:     GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/social/complete/google-oauth2/?state=GjvbQRt2HA8321312lVJTAGAdgUMbV&code=4/dRm-4hiTjN4PXB7P312312321d5DEyhGgsu9tG4Ik
Django Version:     1.8.2
Exception Type:     NoReverseMatch
Exception Value:    

Reverse for 'authorize' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{}' not found. 0 pattern(s) tried: []

Exception Location:     /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py in _reverse_with_prefix, line 496
    Python Executable:  /usr/bin/python
Python Version:     2.7.6</pre>
```

My django settings are:

```
    'oauth2_provider',
    'social.apps.django_app.default',
    'rest_framework_social_oauth2',
)

MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
)

ROOT_URLCONF = 'Cofipy.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [
            os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates'),
            os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'message/templates'),
        ],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
                'friends.context_processors.friends_requests',
                'cofipy_app.context_processors.ideea',
                'social.apps.django_app.context_processors.backends',
                'social.apps.django_app.context_processors.login_redirect',
            ],
        },
    },
]



REST_FRAMEWORK = {

    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': (
        # OAuth
    'oauth2_provider.ext.rest_framework.OAuth2Authentication',
        'rest_framework_social_oauth2.authentication.SocialAuthentication',
    )
}


AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = (

    # Others auth providers (e.g. Google, OpenId, etc)

    'social.backends.google.GoogleOAuth2', 

    # Facebook OAuth2
    'social.backends.facebook.FacebookAppOAuth2',
    'social.backends.facebook.FacebookOAuth2',

    # django-rest-framework-social-oauth2
    'rest_framework_social_oauth2.backends.DjangoOAuth2',

    # Django
    'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend',

)

SOCIAL_AUTH_PIPELINE = (
    'social.pipeline.social_auth.social_details',
    'social.pipeline.social_auth.social_uid',
    'social.pipeline.social_auth.auth_allowed',
    'social.pipeline.social_auth.social_user',
    'social.pipeline.social_auth.associate_user',
    'social.pipeline.social_auth.load_extra_data',
)

LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = "/profile"

SOCIAL_AUTH_GOOGLE_OAUTH2_KEY = 'xxxx'
SOCIAL_AUTH_GOOGLE_OAUTH2_SECRET = 'xxxx'

# Google OAuth2 (google-oauth2)
SOCIAL_AUTH_GOOGLE_OAUTH2_IGNORE_DEFAULT_SCOPE = True
SOCIAL_AUTH_GOOGLE_OAUTH2_SCOPE = [
    'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email',
    'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile'
]

SOCIAL_AUTH_FACEBOOK_KEY = 'xxx'
SOCIAL_AUTH_FACEBOOK_SECRET = 'xxx'
```

urls.py:

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    url(r'^api-auth/', include('rest_framework.urls',namespace='rest_framework')),
    url(r'^', include("cofipy_app.urls")),
    url(r'^', include("friends.urls")),
    url(r'^messages/', include("message.urls")),
    url(r'^userprofile/', include("user_profile.urls")),
    url(r'^profile/', 'cofipy_app.views.profile'),
    url(r'^', include('social.apps.django_app.urls', namespace='social')),

] + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

And I`m trying to access the link using:
a href="{% url 'social:begin' 'google-oauth2' %}"

I will apreciate any kind of help.Thank you!

Comment: The error tells that you should check urls file (the 'social:begin' url not in that file). Did you add social-auth urls to your Cofipy/urls.py file? Maybe you can share you urls.py content to dig into.

Comment: i have the social-auth urls added .. i dont think is about that

Comment: In documentation [link](https://django-social-auth.readthedocs.org/en/latest/configuration.html) the urls are specified by social_auth.urls not social.apps.django_app.urls. If the error not in that part, you can check steps from beginning with controlling PYTHONPATH. Did you use a different package from django-social-auth?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just found the solution:
If you use django-rest-framework-social-oauth2 , on the url file you have to put both urls , or you will get this error :

```
url(r'^social/', include('social.apps.django_app.urls', namespace='social')),
url(r'^auth/', include('rest_framework_social_oauth2.urls')),
```

Thanks